Dialogflow CX and Discord integration goes offline
I made the integration using Github's dialogflow-integrations code, and it's working at first. However, after 3-4 minutes, the bot becomes offline, not answering my input and without an error or anything else in the log.
I inserted event listeners, following google AI Studio instructions, but it doesn't give any response also. The current Timeout is at 3600 seconds.
    bot.on('ready', () => {
        console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
    });

    bot.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.error('Bot disconnected!');
    });

    bot.on('reconnecting', () => {
        console.log('Bot reconnecting...');
    });

    bot.on('error', (error) => { 
        console.error('Discord.js error:', error);
    });

    bot.on('warn', (warning) => {
        console.warn('Discord.js warning:', warning);
    });

The code is the one provided by Dialogflow CX, here is the github code (server.js)
/**
 * TODO(developer):
 * Add your service key to the current folder.
 * Uncomment and fill in these variables.
 */
// const projectId = 'my-project';
// const locationId = 'global';
// const agentId = 'my-agent';
// const languageCode = 'en'
// const discordToken = '...'

const express = require("express")
const server = express()

const {Client} = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client()
require('discord-buttons')(bot);

bot.login(discordToken)
bot.on('ready', () => {console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`)})

const structProtoToJson =
    require('../../botlib/proto_to_json.js').structProtoToJson;

// Imports the Google Cloud Some API library
const {SessionsClient} = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow-cx');

/**
 * Example for regional endpoint:
 *   const locationId = 'us-central1'
 *   const client = new SessionsClient({apiEndpoint:
 * 'us-central1-dialogflow.googleapis.com'})
 */
const client = new SessionsClient(
    {apiEndpoint: locationId + '-dialogflow.googleapis.com'});

/**
 * Converts Discord request to a detectIntent request.
 */
function discordToDetectIntent(discordRequest, sessionPath) {
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: discordRequest.content,
      },
      languageCode,
    },
  };

  return request;
}

/**
 * Takes as input a request from Discord and converts the request to
 * detectIntent request which is used to call the detectIntent() function
 * and finally output the response given by detectIntent().
 */
async function detectIntentResponse(discordRequest) {
  const sessionId = await discordRequest.author.id;
  const sessionPath = client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
      projectId, locationId, agentId, sessionId);

  request = discordToDetectIntent(discordRequest, sessionPath);
  const [response] = await client.detectIntent(request);
  return response;
};

async function convertToDiscordMessage(responses) {
  let replies = [];

  for (let response of responses.queryResult.responseMessages) {
    let reply;

    switch (true) {
      case response.hasOwnProperty('text'): {
        reply = response.text.text.join();
      } break;

      /**
       * For information on the layouts for rich messages on Discord visit:
       * Images and Audio:
       * https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send
       * Buttons:
       * https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components
       */
      case response.hasOwnProperty('payload'): {
        reply = await structProtoToJson(response.payload);
      } break;

      default:
    }
    if (reply) {
      replies.push(reply);
    }
  }

  return replies;
}

/**
 * The check at the beginning is required to make sure that the bot does
 * not respond to its own messages and that it only responds when users
 * directly ask it a question either through direct message or by mentioning
 * it in their message.
 */
bot.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author != bot.user && !message.author.bot &&
      (message.mentions.users.has(bot.user.id) ||
       message.channel.type == 'dm')) {
    const responses = await detectIntentResponse(message);
    var requests = await convertToDiscordMessage(responses);
        
    for (req of requests) {
      try {
        await message.channel.send(req);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.data)
      }
    }
  }
})

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(
      'Your Dialogflow integration server is listening on port ' +
      process.env.PORT);
})

module.exports = {
  discordToDetectIntent,
  convertToDiscordMessage
};

Now, the dockerfile:

# Use the official Node.js 18 image.
   # https://hub.docker.com/_/node
   FROM node:18

   # Create and change to the app directory.
   WORKDIR /usr/src/app

   # Set this environmental variable to the integration you want to use
   ENV INTEGRATION=YOUR_INTEGRATION

   # Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
   # A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied.
   # Copying this separately prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
   COPY ${INTEGRATION}/package*.json ./

   # Install production dependencies.
   RUN npm install --only=production

   # Copy local code to the container image.
   COPY . .

   # Run the web service on container startup.
   WORKDIR ${INTEGRATION}
   CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

About the logs, they're too extensive to put here, exceeding the  character limit. However, as said previously, it doesn't trigger any error, nor generate any log to or before shutdown. Anyway, here are the final logs:
{
  "textPayload": "Logged in as Faker_Test#9937!",
  "insertId": "67129ed2000d291963c4a3df",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "service_name": "dialogflow-discord",
      "location": "southamerica-east1",
      "project_id": "risingstars-423221",
      "configuration_name": "dialogflow-discord",
      "revision_name": "dialogflow-discord-00005-sbr"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-10-18T17:45:54.862489Z",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "007989f2a1eea7d15f8db94101c155e8254819f918537d66b07e080cbf5fd872a7f2cc02fd2445db8ed9b61a810f61a308e357d707bb3a9bdaf995bc7c1458aa234a0584"
  },
  "logName": "projects/risingstars-423221/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstdout",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-10-18T17:45:55.128285276Z"
}

{
  "textPayload": "Logged in as Faker_Test#9937!",
  "insertId": "67129ee0000054e6930df4f5",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "revision_name": "dialogflow-discord-00005-sbr",
      "service_name": "dialogflow-discord",
      "configuration_name": "dialogflow-discord",
      "location": "southamerica-east1",
      "project_id": "risingstars-423221"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-10-18T17:46:08.021734Z",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "007989f2a185fa55e5ec862ee63941bd5999d07415d055e31c08f8f5e7002a1f233582b86cce73be809396e26dc5558ba33c5965e6d02c756437203297ab4a168aedeef00d"
  },
  "logName": "projects/risingstars-423221/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstdout",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-10-18T17:46:08.024903812Z"
}

{
  "textPayload": "undefined",
  "insertId": "67129f77000d2956e5c4db74",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "risingstars-423221",
      "location": "southamerica-east1",
      "configuration_name": "dialogflow-discord",
      "service_name": "dialogflow-discord",
      "revision_name": "dialogflow-discord-00005-sbr"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-10-18T17:48:39.862550Z",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "007989f2a1eea7d15f8db94101c155e8254819f918537d66b07e080cbf5fd872a7f2cc02fd2445db8ed9b61a810f61a308e357d707bb3a9bdaf995bc7c1458aa234a0584"
  },
  "logName": "projects/risingstars-423221/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstdout",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-10-18T17:48:39.869509540Z"
}

